# Upgrade from Magento CE 2.1.8 to 2.2.2 - GETTING ERROR : Element 'block', attribute 'class': [facet 'pattern'] is not accepted by the pattern

Tags: migration, magento2.2.2

i am getting below error while Upgrade from Magento CE 2.1.8 to 2.2.2.

Admin is working well.

Front end giving error as below. please help me.

```
   1 exception(s):
         Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 
         'block', attribute 'class': [facet 'pattern'] The value 
         '\\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template' is not accepted by the pattern 
         '[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*(\\[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*)*'.
         Line: 717

        Element 'block', attribute 'class': 
        '\\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template' is not a valid value of the 
        atomic type 'blockClassType'.
        Line: 717

        Element 'customer_logged_in': This element is not expected. Expected is one 
        of ( attribute, block, referenceBlock, referenceContainer, container, move, 
        uiComponent ).
        Line: 724

        Element 'block', attribute 'remove': The attribute 'remove' is not allowed.
        Line: 818

        Element 'move', attribute 'name': The attribute 'name' is not allowed.
        Line: 907

        Element 'move', attribute 'name': The attribute 'name' is not allowed.
        Line: 908

        Element 'remove': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( block, 
        container, referenceBlock, referenceContainer, uiComponent ).
        Line: 927


        Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 
         'block', attribute 'class': [facet 'pattern'] The value '\\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template' is not accepted by the pattern '[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*(\\[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*)*'.
    Line: 717

    Element 'block', attribute 'class': '\\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'blockClassType'.
    Line: 717

    Element 'customer_logged_in': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( attribute, block, referenceBlock, referenceContainer, container, move, uiComponent ).
    Line: 724

    Element 'block', attribute 'remove': The attribute 'remove' is not allowed.
    Line: 818

    Element 'move', attribute 'name': The attribute 'name' is not allowed.
    Line: 907

    Element 'move', attribute 'name': The attribute 'name' is not allowed.
    Line: 908

    Element 'remove': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( block, container, referenceBlock, referenceContainer, uiComponent ).
    Line: 927

    #0 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(115): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('<layout xmlns:x...')
    #1 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<layout xmlns:x...', Object(Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState), Array, NULL, '/home/prabhsim/...', '%message%\nLine:...')
    #2 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
    #3 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
    #4 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php(42): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
    #5 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php(141): Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom(Array)
    #6 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(461): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid('<layout xmlns:x...', 'layout_merged', false)
    #7 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(442): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout('LAYOUT_frontend...', '<body>\n   <refe...')
    #8 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load(Array)
    #9 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor->load()
    #10 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(63): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates()
    #11 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(254): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
    #12 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(875): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
    #13 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(414): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('page_content_he...')
    #14 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/module-cms/Helper/Page.php(171): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock('page_content_he...')
    #15 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Index/Index.php(43): Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage(Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), 'bigmart-home-pa...')
    #16 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index->execute(NULL)
    #17 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->execute()
    #18 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #19 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
    #20 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #21 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
    #22 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #23 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #24 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
    #25 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #26 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #27 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #28 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #29 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #30 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
    #31 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #32 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
    #33 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
    #34 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
    #35 {main}
```

Comment: You need to fix these errors one by one. XML syntax differ for M2.2. You need to analyse it one by  one in your theme and modules

Comment: M2.2 parses xml very thoroughly. 'remove'  cannot be used . its deprecated in 2.2

Comment: check your xmls from DB also while fixing(For design)

Comment: Also go through the link for css/js/scripts http://ahmadvaqaskhan.blogspot.in/2018/02/magento-21x-vs-22x-difference-in.html

Comment: In theme i have found below code in xml file. 
/app/design/frontend/Venustheme/bigmart/Ves_Blog/layout/default.xml file

 <head>
  <css src="Ves_Blog::css/styles.css" />
  <remove src="Ves_Blog::css/owl.carousel.min.css" />
  <remove src="Ves_Blog::css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 </head>

so here  i have to remove "remove" tag ?

Comment: Syntax for remove : <referenceBlock name="block_name" remove="true"/>. Need to check for css remove. remove tag is not used in 2.2

Comment: remove leading backslashes: '\\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template' -> 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template'

Comment: Yes i have removed that leading backslashes and removed "remove" tag from all xml files. that remove tag for css is not an issue.
Now i have remaining 2 more error from error list.

This are that error which i need to resolve.
Element 'block', attribute 'remove': The attribute 'remove' is not allowed.
Line: 818

Element 'move', attribute 'name': The attribute 'name' is not allowed.
Line: 907

Comment: #6 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(461): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid('<layout xmlns:x...', 'layout_merged', false)  -  XML is being validated. Check this xml in files or DB. Or go to this file and print your xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix these errors one by one. XML syntax differ for M2.2. You need to analyse it one by one in your theme and modules .

M2.2 parses xml very thoroughly. 'remove' cannot be used . its deprecated in 2.2

Check your xmls from DB also while fixing(For design)

M2.1 - `<remove name="block_name"/>`

M2.2 - `<referenceBlock name="block_name" remove="true"/>`

Remove leading backslashes: '\\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template' -> 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template'

You need to fix these.

Also go through the link for css/js/scripts http://ahmadvaqaskhan.blogspot.in/2018/02/magento-21x-vs-22x-difference-in.html

Comment: Yes i have removed that leading backslashes and removed "remove" tag from all xml files. that remove tag for css is not an issue. Now i have remaining 2 more error from error list. This are that error which i need to resolve. Element 'block', attribute 'remove': The attribute 'remove' is not allowed. Line: 818 Element 'move', attribute 'name': The attribute 'name' is not allowed. Line: 907

Comment: all error is solved after setup:upgrade command i am getting one more error.


Like ::                    Merge for content type '' is not supported.

Comment: please elaborate the error. Is it listed in your above post

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same error with removing the attributes without value.

From:

```
<block class="" name="" template="Magento_Theme::video_stream.phtml" />
```

to:

```
<block template="Magento_Theme::video_stream.phtml" />
```